# Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): state.cartItems is undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, frontend, mern

I was a following a MERN STACK tutorial and while setting my cart
This is the error I am getting but, I console.log the data in my reducer and it's showing but don't know why is it showing this error

```
Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): state.cartItems is undefined
```

Also, why is the tutor using localStorage for storing data , Can't we directly send it to reducer after fetching Cart Action...
How is it related

Thank You

**CART ACTION**

```js
import { ADD_TO_CART } from '../constants/CartConstants';
import axios from "axios";

export const addToCart = (id, qty) => async (dispatch, getState) => {

    const { data } = await axios.get(`/api/products/${id}`);

    dispatch({
        type: ADD_TO_CART,
        payload: {
            product: data._id,
            name: data.name,
            image: data.image,
            price: data.price,
            countInStock: data.countInStock,
            qty
        }

    })

    localStorage.setItem('cartItems', JSON.stringify(getState().cart.cartItems))
```

**STORE**

```js
import {createStore , applyMiddleware, combineReducers} from 'redux';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk'
import {composeWithDevTools} from 'redux-devtools-extension';
import {productListReducer , productDetailsReducer } from './reducers/productReducer' ;
import {cartReducer} from "./reducers/cartReducer"

const reducer = combineReducers({
    productList: productListReducer,
    productDetails:productDetailsReducer,
    cart: cartReducer
});

const cartItemsFromStorage = localStorage.getItem('cartItems') ? JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('cartItems')) : []

const initialState = {
    cart: cartItemsFromStorage
};

const middleware = [thunk];
const store = createStore(reducer , initialState ,   composeWithDevTools(applyMiddleware(...middleware)))

//composite with dev tools is used to connect our store with our devtools

export default store;
```

**CART REDUCER**

```js
import { ADD_TO_CART } from '../constants/CartConstants';

export const cartReducer = (state = { cartItems: [] }, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case ADD_TO_CART:
            const item = action.payload;
            const existItem = state.cartItems.find((x) => x.product === item.product)
            console.log(existItem)

            if (existItem) {
                return {
                    ...state,
                    cartItems: state.cartItems.map(x => x.product === existItem.product ? item : x)
                }
            } else {
                return {
                    ...state,
                    cartItems: [...state.cartItems, item]
                }
            }
        default:
            return state
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show us where you get the error? Your component's code isn't here which is where you get the error most probably

Comment: Try modifying the `initialState` inside `store` file to `cart: { cartItems: cartItemsFromStorage }`. Your instructors is saving the cart to `localStorage` for data persistent because after refresh, your cart will be empty again

Comment: @SinanYaman Thank you for responding.. The browser is showing that error is at cartReducer File

Comment: You must have modified the state somewhere. Just based on reducer's code, your `state.cartItems` should not be undefined

Comment: @SinanYaman@wyfy There is problem with localStorage , I checked in my browser for localStorage , it's showing nothing...Also I removed my localStorage function and Reducer is working fine without it .. Do you guys have any idea , why It's not working    Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i know it is an old question,but in case someone is facing the same  problem, the answer is

to replace this:

```
const initialState = {cart: cartItemsFromStorage};
```

with this:

```
const initialState = { cart: { cartItems: cartItemsFromStorage } };
```

in the store.js

Answer (score 0):

Make sure this matches your state structure

```
localStorage.setItem('cartItems', JSON.stringify(getState().*cart.cartItems*))
```

If you named differently, it may change e.g

```
cartReducer.cartItems
```